# How to free c++ memory vector<int> * arr?

Tags: c++, vector, memory-management, std

I have a `vector<int>* arr`, which is actually a 2D array.

```
arr =  new vector<int> [size];
```

Is it ok that I just do

```
delete arr;
```

Will `arr[i]` be automatically be deleted, since it is a standard vector?

Comment: Yuk @ dynamically allocating containers. Why?

Comment: If you worked for me I'd fire you for writing code like that.

Comment: thank you guys for your help, much appreciated. I was trying to implement vector of vectors, and this http://www.codepedia.com/1/Cpp2dVector is a great help

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you should be using `delete[]` when you used `new[]`.

But this is madness. You're using nice happy friendly containers for one dimension, then undoing all the goodness by resorting to manual dynamic allocation for the outer dimension.

Instead, just use a `std::vector<std::vector<int> >`, or flatten the two dimensions into a single vector.

Comment: This is worth +1 for "But this is madness.".

Answer (score 6):

Your code is broken. You should be using `delete[]` with `new[]`:

```
delete[] arr;
```

Once you fix this, your code will work correctly.

I have to agree with the commenters that a C-style array of vectors looks a bit crazy.
Why not use a vector of vectors instead? That'll take care of memory management for you.

Comment: I wouldn't exactly call creating a C-style array of `vector`s "fine".  I would call it crazy.

Comment: True, true. If you can't use static allocation, use some kind of managed pointer. If nothing else, it will gain you exception safety.

Answer (score 2):

You're allocating an array of vectors there. So you'll need array delete:

```
delete [] arr;
```

If you were intending to allocate a vector of 'size' elements, you need:

```
arr =  new vector<int>(size); // don't use array delete for this though!
```